# Set selected value of a 'Select' HTML control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How can I set the selected value of a `Select` HTML control from a code-behind file using ASP.NET and C#?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are `FindByText` and `FindByValue` functions available:

```
ListItem li = Select1.Items.FindByText("Three");
ListItem li = Select1.Items.FindByValue("3");
li.Selected = true;
```

Comment: It's good even with v3.5 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection_members(v=VS.90).aspx .

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<select id="selUserFilterOptions" runat="server">
   <option value="1">apple</option>
   <option value="2">orange</option>
   <option value="3">strawberry</option>
</select>
```

C#:

```
string fruitId = selUserFilterOptions.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Awesome! I was juggling with `.SelectedIndex` and `Items` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<=Select1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (Select1.Items[i].Value = valueToSelect)
    {
        Select1.Items[i].Selected = true;
        // Try this too - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.selectedindex(v=VS.90).aspx
        //Select1.SelectedIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to iterate. there are methods given. check my answer.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: check the link from my comment in your answer

Comment: Its .net 3.5 Framework Documentation. I have tested in .net 4.0. Could you check at your end?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following code to get the text of the selected option of HTML Select:

```
var selectedText = Select1.Items[Select1.SelectedIndex].Text.Trim();
```

`Select1` is the ID of your HTML select control.