# Obtain selected value from dropdown in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, drop-down-menu, code-behind

I have the follwing dropdown list and to get the selected value with javascript is easy enough.

```
<select id="FirstDropDown" runat="server" onchange="ValidatePrimaryDropDown();" > 
                    <option>[Please Select Yes Or No]</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>

var e = document.getElementById("FirstDropDown");
var dropDownFirst = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

I prefer to use this dropdown as apposed to `'asp:DropDownList'`.

How can I retrieve the selected value in code behind C#?

Comment: Show some code man. But anyway, if it's runat="server", then you should have some intellisense. What item looks the most useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are FindByText and FindByValue function available.

```
ListItem li = Select1.Items.FindByText("Three");
ListItem li = Select1.Items.FindByValue("3");
li.Selected = true;
```

[Link to source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700121/how-to-set-selected-value-text-of-a-html-select-control)

Answer (score 0):

Is that an aspx page? If so, add a **name** attribute to your select and use

```
Requets.Form["elementName"];
```

in aspx.cs.

Btw: to your javascript code:  is there any particular reason why are you using DOM selection instead of jquery? In jquery you wold just use

```
var selectedItem = $("#FirstDropDown").find(":selected").text()
```