# Set selected values from server-side to bootstrap-multiple-select

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

For [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) I want to set selected values from server side. ( I work with ASP.Net). As I read, I should add to name of select `[]` to get multiple values. But ASP.Net doesn't give opportunity to make this. So I don't know how to make it.

I try just set my list of selected values as value to my select, but this doesn't help.

```
private void LoadPlatform(IEnumerable<string> platforms) {
  try {
    selectPlatforms.Value = string.Join(",", platforms);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IExeptionLogger>().Log(ex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add runat="server" to your select :

```
<select id="Select1" runat="server" name="D1">

</select>
```

Then you can add datasource the normal way:

```
 Select1.DataSource = platforms; // or a dataset 
 Select1.DataTextField = "name"; 
 Select1.DataValueField = "id";
 Select1.DataBind();
```

The other way would be to call a webmethod and return Json then populate it by Jquery :

```
  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items += "<option value='" + val.id+ "'>" + val.value+ "</option>";    
  });    
  $('#Select1').html(items);
```

if you want to set the default selected item:

```
ListItem li = Select1.Items.FindByText("Three");
ListItem li = Select1.Items.FindByValue("3");
li.Selected = true;
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700121/how-to-set-selected-value-text-of-a-html-select-control)

Comment: in this case i set what would filled that select, but not what would be selected. Or i am wrong?

Comment: do you want to set the default selected item of dropdown? if so see my edit

Comment: on button click, i write selected values to session, then make some operation with that values. But when i init control, where select are, i want to set selected values that are still in session. Like just add "tick" - yes this values were selected at previous time