# Select option with C#

Tags: c#

Hello I have the following HTML code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="alertatxt" CssClass="hidden" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <select class="form-control" required="" id="id" name="id" runat="server">
 </select>
```

My select have elements for example (1, 2, 3, 4... etc.) what I want to do is on page_load shows a determinate element as selected, what I'm trying is the following code:

```
int idNumber = 1;
id.SelectedIndex = idNumber;
```

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to solve this with the following code:

```
string idN = Session["Alerta"].ToString();
ListItem li = id.Items.FindByValue(idN.ToString());
li.Selected = true;
```

But now I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

At this line:

> li.Selected = true;

But this doesn't work, how can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700121/how-to-set-selected-value-text-of-a-html-select-control

Comment: @RickS I saw that question but I couldn't implement it to my project

Comment: Why can't you implement it to your project?

Comment: @RickS take a look to my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed **li** is not null before updating its properties?

```
string idN = Session["Alerta"].ToString();
ListItem li = id.Items.FindByValue(idN.ToString());

if (li != null)
    li.Selected = true;
```

Comment: So that means the filter you have on id.Items returns nothing - meaning Alerta is not found

Comment: I put this codeline: Response.Write(Session["Alerta"].ToString()); and shows me "1", so I think that the problem is that I fill the input via AJAX so when my code is executed doesn't found anything